# Laravel ORDER BY

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

In Laravel when we `ORDER BY` our records by multiple fields, is it possible that we should give priority to one of the fields that we want to order it?

Ex: Is it possible that we should give priority to email?

```
User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('email', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: If you do 
User::orderBy('email', 'ASC')
->orderBy('name', 'DESC')
->get();

What happens ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `->orderBy()`s are applied in sequence, so you just have to change the order of your `->orderBy()`s in order to change which field is sorted first.

You can see this yourself by dumping the sql generated:

#### Name First:

`dd(User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')->orderBy('email', 'ASC')->toSql());`

Output of DD: `` "select * from `users` order by `name` desc, `email` asc" ``

#### Email First:

`dd(User::orderBy('email', 'ASC')->orderBy('name', 'DESC')->toSql());`

Output of DD: `` "select * from `users` order by `email` asc, `name` desc" ``